# Preloading with React.lazy

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting, react-loadable

`react-loadable` exposes a very nice method `YourLoadableComponent.preload()` thanks to which you can easily preload component before it gets rendered whenever you want (`onMouseOver` etc).

I can see I can do something like: https://github.com/pomber/react-lazy-preload-demo/pull/8/commits/126c1bf6e2a23b3e3f7eb0ffb1b4db260516643f
so to call `import()` manually, store the resulting `Promise` in some variable and then pass it to `React.lazy()`. However it can be a bit too verbose and problematic if I wanted to preload on some class method call or in lifecycle hook.

Any other alternatives to above approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give https://github.com/ianschmitz/react-lazy-with-preload a try. Seems to suite your use case nicely!